# QVideoWidget is new window after leaving fullscreen

Tags: c++, qt

I want my video player to show the `QVideoWidget` fullscreen when double clicking. I have created a new class, inherited the `QVideoWidget` class and I then overwritten the `mousDoubleClickEvent`.

```
//Mouse event in new VideoWidget Class
void VideoWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if( isFullScreen() )
        showNormal();
    else
        setFullScreen( true ); //Show in fullscreen
}
```

The VideoWidget is used in my main window where (later) all other widgets are placed.

```
void MainWindow::setupUi()
{
    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget( this );
    QHBoxLayout* centralLayout = new QHBoxLayout( centralWidget );

    videoWidget = new VideoWidget( this );

    setCentralWidget( centralWidget );
    centralLayout->addWidget( videoWidget );
}
```

The problem is now that whenver I enter the full screen mode by double click and exit again by double click, the video widget is no longer in the MainWindow. It is a new window. How do I place it back to its old position again?

Edit:
The `videoWidget` seems to be in a new window AND in my `centralLayout`. But when I close the new window it disappears in my `centralLayout` too.

Comment: @ov1d1u No, I recently thought about this problem and came up with a "solution". However, I just thought about it very short and did not test it yet. When you double click it the first time you should hide your main window and create a new window in fullscreen mode with the video widget. On the next double click you will simply delete the window and show your mainwindow again and (maybe) seek to the position. You will probably have to do some other things to make it work but that was my basic thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think video widget is being detached from main window when toggling fullscreen. Maybe you should try to re-add it to layout manually after returning to normal mode.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too but I don't know how. I emitted a signal when the video widget leaves / enters fullscreen and catch it in my main window. When it leaves the fullscreen it should be added with the insertWidget() function but it doesnt work.